# <path> created inside <svg> using GWT DOM class doesn't show up in the screen

Tags: dom, gwt, svg

I want to create a simple SVG graphics in GWT using only DOM manipulation (via DOM class). Eventually (after compilation with GWT compiler), I want to have a `<path>` element inside `<svg>` element.

The final effect should look, more or less, as follows:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <svg>
   <path stroke="black" d="M200 200 L300 150"></path>
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the java GWT code which should create such effect:

```
    Element svg = DOM.createElement("svg");
    Document.get().getBody().appendChild(svg);

    Element path = DOM.createElement("path");
    path.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
    path.setAttribute("d", "M200 200 L300 150");
    svg.appendChild(path);
```

The problem is that the path doesn't show up in the browser (I can see only white background). What's very interesting, if I see the source of the page via the browser, copy the whole source (from `<html>` to `</html>`), paste it to a new blank document in a text editor, save it to the hard drive as HTML file and open it in the browser, the path is displayed (it means the source is updated correctly).

**Why the path doesn't show up in the screen for the first time** (and does show up for the second time)?

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:**
As it turns out, using ComplexPanel and XML namespace works if I want to draw a `<path>` element. But now I want to draw a **text along path**.

The final effect should look like this:

```
<svg>
 <defs>
  <path id="myPath" stroke="black" d="M75,20 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0"></path>
 </defs>
 <text x="10" y="100">
  <textPath xlink:href="#myPath">Text along a curved path...</textPath>
 </text>
</svg>
```

The java code which should generate it:

```
class SVGPanel extends ComplexPanel {
    private static final String SVG_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    public SVGPanel() {
        setElement(createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "svg"));
        showcaseSVG();
    }

    private void showcaseSVG() {
        Element defs = createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "defs");
        getElement().appendChild(defs);

        Element path = createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "path");
        path.setAttribute("id", "myPath");
        path.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
        path.setAttribute("d", "M75,20 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0");
        defs.appendChild(path);

        Element text = createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "text");
        text.setAttribute("x", "10");
        text.setAttribute("y", "100");
        getElement().appendChild(text);

        Element textPath = createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "textPath");
        textPath.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#myPath");
        textPath.setInnerText("Text along a curved path...");
        text.appendChild(textPath);
    }

    private native Element createElementNS(final String ns,
            final String name)/*-{
        return document.createElementNS(ns, name);
    }-*/;
}
```

The text along path **doesn't show up**. Of course, as previously, if I copy the generated source to a new HTML file and open it in the browser, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use setAttributeNS, passing in the xlink namespace.

So in the given code above, replace:

```
textPath.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#myPath");
```

With:

```
textPath.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#myPath");
```

Comment: Yes, **it works**! Thank you, Erik. Of course, textPath element doesn't have a method setAttributeNS (I guess you used a mental shortcut). So I created a JSNI method    `private native void setAttributeNS(String uri, Element elem, String attr, String value) /*-{
   elem.setAttributeNS(uri, attr, value);
  }-*/;` and called it with suitable parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem seems to be that there is no namespace defined for the svg. Also svgs seem to only be drawn in GWT if they are set in a ComplexPanel....

Anyway here is a example how to draw a SVG element with GWT.

```
package XXXXXXX;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel;

public class SVGPanel extends ComplexPanel {
    private static final String SVG_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    public SVGPanel() {
        setElement(createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "svg"));
        showcaseSVG(); // Demonstrate that SVG works! Inexplicably!
    }

    private void showcaseSVG() {
        Element svgElement = createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "circle");
        svgElement.setAttribute("cx", "50");
        svgElement.setAttribute("cy", "50");
        svgElement.setAttribute("r", "30");
        getElement().appendChild(svgElement);
    }

    private static native Element createElementNS(final String ns,
            final String name)/*-{ 
        return document.createElementNS(ns, name);
    }-*/;
}
```

Adding this to your rootpanel draws the specified path.

Sources: http://de.w3support.net/index.php?db=so&id=691809

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: **Thank you**, Stefan, for your very helpful answer. You're right, now the `<path>` element **does show up** (it's rendered). The problem I described above is a simplicity of another, similar goal. What I want to achieve, is a text along path which is `<textpath>` element inside `<text>`. Unfortunately, **it doesn't work** using your solution with ComplexPanel and XML namespace. The simple test case and other details will be added in my initial question.